# Laravel model create not null violation when value is set

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "title" violates not-null constraint
```

is thrown when executing the create function on the product model. This is the code I am executing:

```php
$title = $csvLine[18];
$description = $csvLine[0];
$link = $csvLine[17];

$productTemp = Product::create([
 'title' => $title,
 'description' => $description,
 'link' => $link,
]);
```

When adding an echo statement inbetween assigning csv values to variable and creating the product, it is not null. But when I create it immediatly throws a null contrains violation.

Comment: Could it be something to do with mass assignment?, i.e. you've not declared the title as a fillable in the products model

Comment: You were right, my model fillables were switched somehow. I copied a model and changed the wrong fillables apparently. If you put it as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: it's okay, done by Turbo already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have not declared `title` as fillable in the `Products` model.